# Invalid operands to binary expression(when using two overloaded operators at the same time)

Tags: c++

I am receiving the following error:`error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'Matrix')`
And the related code is like:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &b){
    Matrix C(r,c);
    int i,j;
    if(b.r!=r||b.c!=c)
        printf("invalid operation!");
    else {for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            C.data[i][j]=data[i][j]+b.data[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    }
    return C;
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, Matrix &A){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<A.r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<A.c;j++)
        {
            out<<setw(6)<<A.data[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

&

```
    cout<<"A + B:"<<endl;
    cout << (A + B) <<endl;
```

But after I changed the 2nd part into this,it just went well:

```
    Matrix C;
    cout<<"A + B:"<<endl;
    cout << C <<endl;
```

I'm really confused what's wrong with the original code……actually it's part of the fixed framework of  my programming homework,and I'm not allowed to change it. QAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(A + B)
```

The result of this addition operation is a temporary value.

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, Matrix &A){
```

Temporaries do not bind, or convert, to mutable references. C++ does not work this way. They only bind to `const` references. Just change the 2nd parameter of this `operator<<` overload to `const Matrix &`, and make any appropriate changes to the contents of this overload, as needed (it may be necessary to change `Matrix`'s mysterious "data" member's `operator[]` overload as well, since it now gets invoked on a `const` class instance).